# Formato a 24 horas de Data-Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito como cambiar el formato data-time a 24 horas.

Estoy trabajando con C# MVC5

**Este es mi Modelo**

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha y Hora de Inicio")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")]
public System.DateTime fechaHoraInicio { get; set; }
```

**Mis Vistas**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fechaHoraInicio, new { type = "datetime-local" })
```

Agradezco desde ya el interés.

Answer (score 2):

Usa la función de  upper-case HH para el formato de 24h:

```
String s = curr.ToString("HH:mm");
```

más explicación: [DateTime:toString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
[ Display(Name = "Fecha y Hora de Inicio") ]
[ DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString  =  @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm}",  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true) ]
```

Comment: ¿qué es esto, Alex, una edición a tu pregunta o la solución? Si quieres editar tu pregunta, **[haz click aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/66874/edit)**. Si esto soluciona tu problema, recuerda aceptar tu respuesta y describir porqué esto soluciona tu problema.